# Why does AWS Athena completly outperform a AWS Glue at querying the MAX of a string column in a large dataset?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a large dataset that comes from an IoT input with aproximately 5000 million rows. The dataset is stored into S3 in a single directory in the format of parquet. Each subset of rows corresponding to one day it's stored into a different parquet, all of them in the same directory. The dataset, in essence, looks like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | datestring (type: object) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | value3 | "2023/04/24" |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

This dataset is then crawled daily into the Glue Catalog. Please note I am aware there are a million ways to improve this method of storage; however, that is not my question.

So: within the context of a Glue Pipeline, it was needed to query the max date from the datestring column in the whole dataset. My surprise comes from the difference in between these two methods inside the Glue execution context:

- Reading the spark dataframe with createDynamicFrame, whether is fromOptions or fromCatalog. Using pyspark.sql.functions.max to query the maximum of the datestring column (which turns to be the maximum date as lexicographic order is analog in this case).
- Using Athena to query from catalog an SQL statement like "SELECT MAX(datestring) FROM table".

The first method takes 20 minutes with 10 standard workers. The second method takes 2 seconds. How is this possible? What is the reason behind? I am very curious about it.

I first guessed it happens because Athena leverages the metadata stored by the crawler. But then, why would it take 20 minutes when using the createDynamicFrame.**fromCatalog** as well?

Comment: This is not an answer because it's speculation. One possible difference between Athena and Glue is that Athena recognizes that it's performing a single-column operation on a Parquet file, and reads/processes only the parts of the file that contain that column's data. Versus Glue, which must read the entire file into the dataframe.

Comment: Another might be that Athena assigns far more workers to the task. I have no idea whether it does that or not, but BigQuery does and it's competing in the same space.

Comment: @kdgregory That is an interesting guess. However I have my doubts about Glue having to read the entire file: Glue execution context is based on Spark, and parquet files are columnar storage. One of the main perks of Spark is predicate pushdown and DAG optimization, so if I query the max value of a column, it should only scan that column... right?

Answer (score 1):

create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog() method will be slower than using Athena query for your situation. This is because the Glue job needs to load the entire dataset into memory (if it fits in if not other objects will wait in the queue. This depends on your resource allocation for example 10 DPU's) before applying the max() function. In contrast, Athena query can execute the max() function directly on the dataset in S3 without loading it into memory.

That's what I know, but there might be more reasons.